# What does it mean for a set to be relatively open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The definition is that if we are given that Y $\subseteq$ X (where X is a metric space), a subset E of Y is open relative to Y if and only if E=Y $\cap$ G for some open subset G of X.

I'm having trouble understanding intuitively what this is saying. I've read some of the similar questions and still am not grasping the concept.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could someone explain the concept of a set being "open relative" to another set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210815/could-someone-explain-the-concept-of-a-set-being-open-relative-to-another-set)

Answer (score 0):

For example, consider the subset $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Open intervals are open in this set, but so are intervals of the form $[0,x)$ and $(x,1]$. The first is $(-\infty,x)\cap [0,1]$ and the second is $(x,\infty)\cap [0,1]$. $[0,x)$ and $(x,1]$ are not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but they are open in $[0,1]$ relative to the topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why does that matter? I guess I'm not seeing where the definition comes in

Comment: See edit above. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given topological space on $X$ and $Y\subset X$, we can form a topological space on $Y$ (called the subspace topology) in a very natural way: the sets in $Y$ that are open are the sets $E\cap Y$ where $E$ is open in $X$. You can check the axioms of a topological space to see that the subspace topology satisfies them.

Now the terminology "open relative to $Y$" should be clear: $E$ is "open relative to $Y$" if $E$ is open in the subspace topology on $Y$ relative to the topology on $X$.